# Show box by clicking on Input

Tags: html, jquery

The box is displayed when the input key is pressed. The problem is that when I use code `.focus` nothing happens.

Friends, how can I solve this problem?
and
Why does the following code not run ?
`$("#send_order_txtCount").focus (function(){ ..... )}`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#number").focus(function() {
      $("#box1").css('display', 'block'); //.fadeIn("slow");
    },
    function() {
      $("#box1").hover(function() {
          $("#box1").css('display', 'block') //.fadeIn("slow");
        },
        function() {
          $("#box1").fadeOut();
        },
        function() {
          $("#box1").fadeOut();
        })
    });
});
```

```css
#box1 {
  display: none;
  width: 30.5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="number" min="0">

<span id="box1"> value =  
    <span class="me1">
        1,000
    </span>
<span class="wbb3"> | 
    </span>
<span class="me1">
        10,000
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Why do you repeat events. Focus event works if you specify a closing parenthesis. Tell the concept of what should happen in your code.

Comment: Please check your syntax. It's quite messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `focusin` event this will get called when input is focus and `.blur` to `fadeOut` your box same for `box`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//when input is focus
$("#number").on('focusin', function() {
  $("#box1").css('display', 'block');
}).blur(function() {
  //when blur focusout
  $("#box1").fadeOut();
});

$("#box1").hover(function() {
    $("#box1").css('display', 'block')
  },
  function() {
    $("#box1").fadeOut();
  });
```

```css
#box1 {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="number" min="0" autocomplete="off">

<span id="box1"> value =  
    <span class="me1">
        1,000
    </span>
<span class="wbb3"> | 
    </span>
<span class="me1">
        10,000
    </span>
</span>
```